# What is issue in this request to Google map engine API

Tags: google-maps-api

i want to use the [batchInsert](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/reference/v1/tables/features/batchInsert) of google map engine,
i am calling this with dojo/request

```
request("https://www.googleapis.com/mapsengine/v1/tables/1453899488279955151311853667273131550346/features/batchInsert",
                    {
                        headers : {
                            "Authorization": 'Bearer '+ token.access_token,
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : null,
                            "X-Requested-With": null,
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        },
                        handleAs : 'json',
                        method : 'POST',
                        data :datastring
                    }
            ).then(function(data){
                        console.log("Got data :"+data);
                    }, function(err){
                        console.log("Got error :"+err.response.text);
                    }, function(evt){
                        console.log("Got Event :"+evt);
                    });
```

Request as below

```
{
"features":[
{"type":"Feature",
"geomerty":
    {
    "type":"Point",
    "coordinates":[-34.678393740116476,150.765380859375]
    },
"properties":
{
"gx_id":"2",
"FID":2,
"sapobjectid":"12345sdf",
"sapobjectname":"Test",
"Features":"Point"}
}
]
}
```

But i am getting the error as

```
Got error :{
"error": {
"errors": [
 {
"domain": "global",
"reason": "required",
"message": "A value is required.",
"locationType": "other",
"location": "features[0].geometry"
}
],
"code": 400,
"message": "A value is required."
}
}
```

Comment: features[0].geometry has a value or is null ? Check the request in debugger for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is only a temporary issue, but at least at this very moment, your request gives an error related to your account limits:

[image]

I'll try further to investigate your problem.

---

Did you realise that's a misspelling into your request: **`geomerty`** ?

Just try again, using **`geometry`** instead.

Comment: problem with the spelling..  :(